# Как передать значение заголовка товара в форму

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно передать название товара в всплывающую форму в которой надпись должна быть такая - "Товар 1 в корзине". делал так:

```
    var nm = $('.v-products-card__title').html();
      $('<div class="ovrl"><div class="incart"><p>' + nm + ' в корзине<\/p><div class="flx"><a href="/cart/" class="gotocart">Перейти в корзину</a><a  class="cls">Вернуться к покупкам<\/a><\/div><\/div><\/div>').appendTo('body');
```

Но выводится заголовок первого элемента на страницы

```
          <div id="product-list">
          <div class="mt1 products product-list">
          {foreach $products as $p}
                  <div class="liss v-products-card__item js-element js-             float-element">
                    <div class="v-products-card__margin">
                      <div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
                        <div class="v-products-card__general">
                          <a class="v-products-card__link" href="{$p.frontend_url}" title="{$p.name}">
                            <div class="category_present">
                                {$badge_html =  $wa->shop->badgeHtml($p.badge)}
                                {if $badge_html}
                                {$badge_html}
                                {/if}
                            </div>

                            <div class="v-products-card__photo">
                              {$_product = $wa->shop->product($p.id)}
                              {$product_image_ids = array_keys($_product.images)}
                              {$slider_image = $_product.images[$product_image_ids[0]]}
                              {$p.image_id = $slider_image.id}
                              {$p.ext = $slider_image.ext}
                              {if $slider_image}
                              {$wa->shop->productImgHtml($p, '220x220', ['itemprop' => 'image', 'alt' => $p.name, 'class' => 'v-products-card__img'])}
                              {else}
                              <img class="v-products-card__img" src="/wa-data/public/shop/themes/maltech/img/dummy500.png" alt="{$p.name}" />
                              {/if}
                            </div>
                            <div class="v-products-card__content">
                              <div class="v-products-card__title"><span class="v-products-card__name">{$p.name}</span></div>

                              <div class="product-description-short">
                                {$product = $items[$p.id]}
                                {$pfrt = 0}
                                {if $product.features}
                                {foreach $product.features as $f_code => $f_value}
                                {if $pfrt < 4}
                                <span class="mt7">{$features[$f_code].name|escape}: </span>
                                {if is_array($f_value)}
                                <span class="mt8">{implode(', ', $f_value)}{if $pfrt < 2};{/if}</span>
                                {else}
                                <span class="mt8">{$f_value}{if $pfrt < 2};{/if}</span>
                                {/if}
                                {$pfrt = $pfrt+1}
                                {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                                {/if}
                              </div>

                              <div class="v-products-card__price-block">
                                <span class="v-products-card__price">{shop_currency_html($p.price)}</span>
                                {if $p.compare_price > 0}
                                <span class="v-products-card__price-old">{shop_currency_html($p.compare_price)}</span>
                                {/if}
                              </div>

                              <div class="v-products-card__bottom">
                              {if $p.rating > 0}
                            {* <div class="v-products-card__rating">{$wa->shop->ratingHtml($p.rating)}</div>  *}
                                <span class=" v-products-card__rating rating nowrap" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" title="{sprintf('[`Average user rating: %s / 5`]', $p.rating)}">
        {$wa->shop->ratingHtml($p.rating, 16)}
    </span>

                              {/if}
                              {$available = $wa->shop->settings('ignore_stock_count') || $p.count === null || $p.count > 0}
                              {if $available}
                              <div class="v-products-card__price-stock"><span class="_in-stock">В наличии</span></div>
                              {else}
                              <div class="v-products-card__price-stock"><span class="_no-stock">Нет в наличии</span></div>
                              {/if}
                              </div>

                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <div class="v-products-card__extra">
                          <a href="{$p.frontend_url}" class="v-products-card__extra-item v-products-card__extra-item_2 v-products-card__extra-item_favorite js-favorites-link" data-id="20"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="v-products-card__extra-name">Подробнее</span></a>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                              <div class="dr10">Добавлен в корзину!</div>
                              {$available = $wa->shop->settings('ignore_stock_count') || $p.count === null || $p.count > 0}
                                {foreach $_product.categories as $c}{if $c.parent_id==15}{if $c.id==18}
                                {$a=1}
                                {else} {$a=0}
                                {/if}{/if}{/foreach}
                              {if $available & $a==0} 
                              <form class="purchase addtocart" {if $p.sku_count > 1}data-url="{$p.frontend_url}{if strpos($p.frontend_url, '?')}&{else}?{/if}cart=1"{/if} method="post" action="{$wa->getUrl('/frontendCart/add')}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{$p.id}">
                              <div class="v-products-card__cart">
                                <button class="v-products-card__add tocart" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Купить</button>
                              </div>
                              </form>
                              <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
                              {else}
                              <div class="v-products-card__cart"><span class="v-products-card__add _disable"><i class="ion-android-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Купить</span></span></div>{/if}

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
  {/foreach}

    //js

                     $("form.addtocart").submit(function () {
var f = $(this);
$.post(f.attr('action'), f.serialize(), function (response) {
  if (response.status == 'ok') {
    var cart_total = $(".cart-total");
    cart_total.closest('#cart-summary').removeClass('empty');
    updateCartSummaryFixedStatus();
    if ($("table.cart").length) {
      $(".content").parent().load(location.href, function () {
        cart_total.html(response.data.total);
      });
    } else {
      var origin = f.closest('.liss');
      var block = $('<div></div>').append(origin.html());
      origin.find('.dr10').show().fadeOut(2000);
      block.css({
        'z-index': 100000,
        top: origin.offset().top,
        left: origin.offset().left,
        width: origin.width() + 'px',
        height: origin.height() + 'px',
        position: 'absolute',
        overflow: 'hidden'
      }).insertAfter(origin).animate({
        top: cart_total.offset().top,
        left: cart_total.offset().left,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        opacity: 0.5
      }, 500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
        cart_total.html(response.data.total);
        $('.cart-count').html(response.data.count);
      });
      var nm = $('.v-products-card__title').html($(this).text());
      $('<div class="ovrl"><div class="incart"><p>' + nm + ' в корзине<\/p><div class="flx"><a href="/cart/" class="gotocart">Перейти в корзину</a><a  class="cls">Вернуться к покупкам<\/a><\/div><\/div><\/div>').appendTo('body');
      $('.ovrl').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.incart').hide();
      });
      $('.cls').click(function () {
        $('.ovrl').hide();
        $('.incart').hide();
      });
    }
  } else if (response.status == 'fail') {
    alert(response.errors);
  }
}, "json");
return false;
```

});

Comment: Вообще такие задачи решаются через this. То есть явный указатель на конкретный заголовок из всей коллекции .v-products-card__title. Для более точного ответа нужен воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: То-есть так: var nm = $('.v-products-card__title').html($(this).text());?

Comment: Ну, я ж не знаю, как именно у Вас всё работает. Мало кода. Сделайте воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Есть товар у которого есть заголовок(название товара). Заголовок выводится так: <div class="v-products-card__title"><span class="v-products-card__name">{$p.name}</span></div>, ниже заголовка есть кнопка в корзину при клике по этой кнопке всплывает форма в которой должно быть написано "Товар(название товара) в корзине". Вот собственно весь пример. Сейчас при клике в всплывающей форме выводится всегда первый товар на странице, а нужно что бы это значение было товара который выбран, тоесть по которому был клик в корзину.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно при нажатие на кнопку получить название товара.

Я бы для этого использовал следующее:

```
$('Кнопка').on('click', function(){
  let name = $(this).closest('родитель').find('название');
  ...
});
```

`$(this)` - определит "положение" относительно кнопки.
`.closest()` - позволяет "дойти" до определённого элемента выше по иерархии. ([подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest))
`.find()` - ищет элемент в текущем элементе. ([подробнее](https://jquery-docs.ru/find/))

Тем самым у меня получается вот такой функционал:

```js
$('.add-basket').on('click', function(){
  let title = $(this) //От текущего элемента..
                    .closest('.info') // возвращаемся к родителю
                    .find('.title') // от родителя ищем .title
                    .text(); // берём текст .title
  
  $('.basket-content')// Далее в .basket-content..
    .append('<div class="item">'+title+'</div>'); // Создаём элемент .item с title
});

// Эт не нужно..
$('.basket .placeholder').on('click', function(){
  $('.basket').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.head {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.backet, .placeholder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.backet {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.placeholder {
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.placeholder:hover, .basket.active .placeholder {
  background: #aaa;
}

.basket-content {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 80px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.basket-content:empty::after {
  content: 'Корзина пуста';
  display: block;
}

.basket.active .basket-content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.content::after,
.info::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.title, .add-basket {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.title {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.add-basket {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-basket:hover {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="head">
  <div class="basket">
    <div class="placeholder">Корзина</div>
    <div class="basket-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Товар A</div>
      <div class="add-basket">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Товар B</div>
      <div class="add-basket">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Товар C</div>
      <div class="add-basket">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Товар D</div>
      <div class="add-basket">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Этого пытаетесь добиться?)

Answer (score 0):

Если кнопка и название товара лежат на одном уровне, то логика может быть такой:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  alert($(this).siblings('.v-products-card__title').text());
});
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
<div class="v-products-card__title"><span class="v-products-card__name">Первое название</span></div>
<button>В корзину</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="product">
<div class="v-products-card__title"><span class="v-products-card__name">Второе название</span></div>
<button>В корзину</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="product">
<div class="v-products-card__title"><span class="v-products-card__name">Третье название</span></div>
<button>В корзину</button>
</div>
<br />
```

То есть по клику на кнопку Вы находите ближайший .v-products-card__title и выводите его.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но в моем случае выдает [object Object] в корзине

Comment: @ilyaaa521, чтобы понять, что именно не так в Вашем случае, я в третий уже раз рекомендую Вам добавить в вопрос полный воспроизводимый код

Comment: Добавил в описание